# How to prevent pages from running together or from combining in PHP

Tags: php, captcha

I have two pages, both in PHP, but when viewing the page, the server combines the two together and serves them as one. How can I prevent this, and receive two separate pages? SuperGlobals are restricted in my environment AND no javascript.

1. Page One (index.php)

This is the index page for the site. I would like to require users to enter a captcha correctly before viewing this page.

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/captcha.php';

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>You Win!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>You Really Win!</h1>
    <h2>Win Baby, Win!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Page Two (captcha.php)

This is the page where the captcha is located and the page that I would like to appear first before the index page.

```php
<?php

//To save time and space, This page is highly abbreviated from the actual php file.

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Gregwar\Captcha\PhraseBuilder;
use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;

$captcha = new CaptchaBuilder;
$captcha->build();
$phrase = $captcha->getPhrase();
$phrase = $_SESSION['phrase'];

$check_phrase = PhraseBuilder::comparePhrases($_SESSION['phrase'], $_POST['phrase']);
if (isset($_SESSION['phrase']) && $check_phrase === true)
{
  header('Location: ' . __DIR__ . '/index.php');
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<form method="post">
    <div>
        Copy the CAPTCHA:
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $captcha->inline(); ?>" alt="Captcha"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="phrase" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

So how do I separate the pages from each other and make the server serve them as two separate pages?

Comment: By not having a require_once there.

Comment: What do you mean by "superglobals are restricted"?

Comment: The index page shouldn't include the captcha, it should redirect to it. Then if the captcha succeeds, it sets a session variable and redirects back to the main page. When the session variable is set, the main page shows normally instead of redirecting to the captcha.

Comment: @Barmar So, instead of using a `require_once`, I should be using a `header("Location: captcha.php")`? Then once the captcha succeeds, I then redirect the user back to `index.php`?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion made by @Barmar was a beginning, but did not place me on home base. The problem was resolved by using a third file that managed redirections between the two files. The entire process is explained in the diagram image provided below.

[Process Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU2tF.png)

1. **index.php**

The use of `require_once` is still facilitated on this file in order to use conditionals to manage redirections. The only thing that changed is the file that is required, and it is the redirect manager file `start.php`.

```php
require_once (start.php)
```

2. **Start.php**

This file is the new addition and discovered resolution to the problem. It uses conditionals to test which page the user should be forwarded to.

```php
if (strcmp($user_secret, $server_secret)
{
  header('Location: index.php')
}
else //inferred not actual
{
 header('Location: captcha.php')
}
```

3. **captcha.php**

Little has changed in the file as well, except for only facilitating the use of `require_once` to use the conditionals therein to direct the use to the index page.

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Gregwar\Captcha\PhraseBuilder;
use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;

$captcha = new CaptchaBuilder;
$captcha->build();
$phrase = $captcha->getPhrase();
$phrase = $_SESSION['phrase'];

$check_phrase = PhraseBuilder::comparePhrases($_SESSION['phrase'], $_POST['phrase']);
if (isset($_SESSION['phrase']) && $check_phrase === true)
{
  require_once 'start.php';
}

?>
<form method="post">
    <div>
        Copy the CAPTCHA:
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $captcha->inline(); ?>" alt="Captcha"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="phrase" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</form>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

AND, it works exactly as I had hoped it would. The code is simpler, more straight forward, and the process is less confusing.